# Installing php-hash on SUSE 10.1

Tags: installation, sles, packages

I need the PHP function hash_hmac which is not part of my distribution on my virtual server running SUSE 10.1.

Trying to install it with yast2 --install php-hash leads to the following message:

```
No installation source is defined.
Only installed packages are displayed.
```

Does anybody know what to do to set these installation sources in order to install php-hash?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the package you're looking for is `php5-mhash`. It's in the update repos, so it should be in the sources. If your provider doesn't have the sources joined, you can download them from download.novell.com.

However, if you're really asking for OpenSUSE 10.1, not SLES 10 SP1, you'll have to google around for an install ISO since that version is no longer updated or supported. Or available in the standard repos.